# Elasticsearch Shard Taking All the Load

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql, bigdata, sharding

I have a sharded cluster composed of 3 Elasticsearch nodes (Version 1.4, I know it's too old) and one indice, the indice itself is divided into 5 shards that are distributed among the 3 cluster nodes. The shards have an average size of 15 gb.

I have a feeling that the shards are very disproportionate, because every-time I relocate the secondary/slave shard number 4 into one of the three nodes, that node take almost the whole load permanently and its load-average rises in a disturbing way in peak times.

Does Elasticsearch offer a shard repartition/re-balacing feature that allows the data to be re-partitioned equally among the shards in order to have the load (reads & writes) balanced equally between the cluster nodes ?

Comment: do you have a some parent-child or nested documents in your index?

Comment: @ArchitSaxena We don't use parent-child documents, but we have nested ones.